# System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have one method getComponent. I am calling this method two times. Once at the time of page loading and another time at the time on the `onchange` event.

Problems: At the time of pageloading the getmethod component will work and Javascript side shows values.

But in case of an `onchange` event it doesn't work. It throws:

> System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '[' at the beginning of List/Set

```
<aura:component controller="ActionController"  implements="force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="theId" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="String[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="wrplst" type="WrapperCriteria[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedValue" type="String"/>
    <aura:handler name="deleteJob" event="c:deleteJobEvt" action="{!c.RemoveClick}" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <p>
        <b>Creating Action Criteria </b>
    </p>
    <h3 class="slds-section-title--divider">
        <b>
            <I> Action Criteria</I>
        </b>
    </h3>
    <table >
        <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
            <th class="head">
                <I>Action</I>
            </th>
            <th class="head">
                <I>Object Name</I>
            </th>
            <th class="head">
                <I>Component</I>
            </th>
            <th class="head">
                <I>Operator</I>
            </th>
            <th class="head">
                <I>Special Operator</I>
            </th>
            <th class="head">
                <I>Special Operator * Value</I>
            </th>
            <th class="head">
                <I>Special Operator / Value</I>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.wrplst.length > 0}">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.wrplst}" var="a">
                <c:NewAction wrp="{!a}" options="{!v.options}" selectedValue=""  idval="{!v.theId}"/>
            </aura:iteration>
        </aura:renderIf>
    </table>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Add row" onclick="{!c.AddRow}" />
    <lightning:button variant="brand"  label="Save" onclick="{!c.saveRow}" />
</aura:component>
```

---

Javascript:

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.pageLoad(component);
        helper.componentVal(component);

    },
    doSomething: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.Method2(component);
    },
    RemoveClick: function(component, event, helper) {
        var selCont = event.getParam("selectedJob");
        var conts = component.get("v.wrplst");
        var contsval = JSON.stringify(conts);

        var Selndex = conts.indexOf(selCont);

        var DeleteLen = conts.length;
        //alert('deleteLen value::::' + DeleteLen);
        var removeAction = component.get("c.removeRow");
        removeAction.setParams({
            "wrvalue": contsval,
            "rowval": Selndex
        });
        removeAction.setCallback(this, function(g) {
            var state = g.getState();
            if (state == 'SUCCESS') {
                alert('success value');
                component.set("v.wrplst", JSON.parse(g.getReturnValue()));
            } else if (state === 'error') {
                alert('error value');
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(removeAction);
    },
    AddRow: function(component, event, helper) {

        var comp1 = component.get("v.wrplst");
        var compJson1 = JSON.stringify(comp1);
        var mapRecords = new Array();
        for (i = 0; i < comp1.length; i++) {
            mapRecords.push(comp1[i]);
        }
        var len = mapRecords.length;

        var newlen = len + 1;

        var addAction = component.get("c.addRow");
        addAction.setParams({
            "wrapval": compJson1,
            "counterval": newlen,
        });
        addAction.setCallback(this, function(res) {
            var state = res.getState();
            if (state == 'SUCCESS') {
                component.set("v.wrplst", JSON.parse(res.getReturnValue()));
            } else if (state == 'ERROR') {
                alert('error');
            } else if (state == 'INCOMPLETE') {
                alert('incompltete');
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(addAction);
    },
    saveRow: function(component, event, helper) {
        var Idx = component.get("v.theId");
        alert('Id value ::::' + Idx);
        var com = component.get("v.wrplst");
        var comJson = JSON.stringify(com);

        var saveAction = component.get("c.saveCall");
        saveAction.setParams({
            "wrvalue": comJson,
            "id": Idx,
        });
        saveAction.setCallback(this, function(re) {
            var state = re.getState();
            if (state === 'SUCCESS') {

            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(saveAction);
    }
});
```

Helper:

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.pageLoad(component);
        helper.componentVal(component);

    },
    doSomething: function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.Method2(component);
    },
    RemoveClick: function(component, event, helper) {
        var selCont = event.getParam("selectedJob");
        var conts = component.get("v.wrplst");
        var contsval = JSON.stringify(conts);

        var Selndex = conts.indexOf(selCont);

        var DeleteLen = conts.length;
        //alert('deleteLen value::::' + DeleteLen);
        var removeAction = component.get("c.removeRow");
        removeAction.setParams({
            "wrvalue": contsval,
            "rowval": Selndex
        });
        removeAction.setCallback(this, function(g) {
            var state = g.getState();
            if (state == 'SUCCESS') {
                alert('success value');
                component.set("v.wrplst", JSON.parse(g.getReturnValue()));
            } else if (state === 'error') {
                alert('error value');
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(removeAction);
    },
    AddRow: function(component, event, helper) {

        var comp1 = component.get("v.wrplst");
        var compJson1 = JSON.stringify(comp1);
        var mapRecords = new Array();
        for (i = 0; i < comp1.length; i++) {
            mapRecords.push(comp1[i]);
        }
        var len = mapRecords.length;

        var newlen = len + 1;

        var addAction = component.get("c.addRow");
        addAction.setParams({
            "wrapval": compJson1,
            "counterval": newlen,
        });
        addAction.setCallback(this, function(res) {
            var state = res.getState();
            if (state == 'SUCCESS') {
                component.set("v.wrplst", JSON.parse(res.getReturnValue()));
            } else if (state == 'ERROR') {
                alert('error');
            } else if (state == 'INCOMPLETE') {
                alert('incompltete');
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(addAction);
    },
    saveRow: function(component, event, helper) {
        var Idx = component.get("v.theId");
        alert('Id value ::::' + Idx);
        var com = component.get("v.wrplst");
        var comJson = JSON.stringify(com);

        var saveAction = component.get("c.saveCall");
        saveAction.setParams({
            "wrvalue": comJson,
            "id": Idx,
        });
        saveAction.setCallback(this, function(re) {
            var state = re.getState();
            if (state === 'SUCCESS') {

            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(saveAction);
    }
});
```

Second Component name:NewAction

```
<aura:component controller="ActionController" >
    <aura:attribute name="wrp" type="WrapperCriteria[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="idval" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute required="true" name="options" type="String[]"/>
    <aura:attribute required="true" name="selectedValue" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="wpchange" type="List" />
    <aura:registerEvent name="deleteJob" type="c:deleteJobEvt"/>

    <tr>
        <td class="cell" style="padding-top:14px;padding-bottom:0px;">
            <p >
                <button type="button" onclick="{!c.RemoveClick}" >remove</button>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td class="cell" >
            <p>

                <lightning:select name="mySelect" label=" " value="{!v.wrp.ObjectApiNAme}" aura:id="obc" onchange="{!c.dosomething}">
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.options}" var="item">
                    <option text="{!item.label}" value="{!item.value}" selected="{!item.selected}"/>
                </aura:iteration>
            </lightning:select> 
            </p>
        </td>
        <td class="cell" >
            <lightning:select name="select" label=" " aura:id="o" >
                <option value="">None</option>
            </lightning:select>
        </td>

        <td class="cell" >
            <p>
                <lightning:select name="selectItem" label=" " value="{!v.wrp.Operator}">
                    <option value="None">None</option>
                    <option value="+ Addition">+ Addition</option>
                    <option value="- Subtract  ">- Subtract</option>
                    <option value="* Multiply ">* Multiply</option>
                    <option value="/ Divide">/ Divide</option>
                </lightning:select>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td class="cell" >
            <p>
                <lightning:select name="selectItem" label=" " value="{!v.wrp.SpecialOperator}">
                    <option value="None">None</option>
                    <option value="*">*</option>
                    <option value="*/">*/</option>
                    <option value="/">/</option>
                </lightning:select>
            </p>
        </td>

        <td class="cell"  style="padding-top:14px;padding-bottom:0px;">
            <p>
                <ui:inputText value="{!v.wrp.specialOperatorValue}"/>
            </p>
        </td>
        <td class="cell"  style="padding-top:14px;padding-bottom:0px;">
            <p>
                <ui:inputText value="{!v.wrp.specialOperatorSlashValue}"/>
            </p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</aura:component>
```

Javascript:

```
({
    RemoveClick: function(component, event, helper) {

        var event1 = component.getEvent("deleteJob");

        event1.setParams({
            'selectedJob': component.get("v.wrp"),
        });
        event1.fire();
    },
    dosomething: function(component, event, helper) {
        var x = component.find("obc").get("v.value");
        alert('x value::::' + x);
        var comp = component.get("v.wrp");
        var compJson = JSON.stringify(comp);
        alert('compJson val ::::' + compJson);
        var Id1 = component.get("v.idval");
        alert('Id1 val::::::' + Id1);

        var Action = component.get("c.getComponent");
        Action.setParams({
            "wrapval": compJson,
            "id": Id1,
        });
        Action.setCallback(this, function(re) {
            var state = re.getState();
            if (state === 'SUCCESS') {
                alert('sucess value :::');
                alert('::::::::' + JSON.stringify(re.getReturnValue()));
                //component.set("v.option",JSON.parse(re.getReturnValue()));
            } else if (state === 'error') {
                alert('error value');
            } else if (state === 'INCOMPLETE') {
                alert('incomplete values:::');

            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(Action);
    }
})
```

Server side:

```
public class ActionController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static string pageLoading(string id) {

        List < Action_Criteria__c > RecordsInserted = new List < Action_Criteria__c > ();
        List < WrapperCriteria > wList = new List < WrapperCriteria > ();
        Criteria_Master__c cmas = new Criteria_Master__c();
        cmas=[select id, Name, Action_Criteria__c, Company_Master__c from Criteria_Master__c where Id =:id];
        RecordsInserted = [select id, Action_Criteria_API_Name__c, Action_Criteria_Field_Name__c, Criteria_Master__c, Object_API_Name__c, Operator__c, Object_Name__c, Special_Operator__c, Special_operator_slash_value__c, Special_operator_value__c from Action_Criteria__c where Criteria_Master__c = : id order by Sequence_No__c];
        system.debug('record Inserted values:::' + RecordsInserted);
        Integer counter=1;
        for (Action_Criteria__c ac: RecordsInserted) {
            WrapperCriteria wrp = new WrapperCriteria();
            wrp.record = ac;
            wrp.ObjectApiNAme = ac.Object_API_Name__c;
            wrp.FieldName = ac.Action_Criteria_API_Name__c;
            wrp.index =counter;
            counter=counter+1;
            wrp.CriteriaMasId = ac.Criteria_Master__c;
            wrp.Operator = ac.Operator__c;
            wrp.SpecialOperator = ac.Special_Operator__c;
            wrp.specialOperatorSlashValue = ac.Special_operator_slash_value__c;
            wrp.specialOperatorValue = ac.Special_operator_value__c;
            wList.add(wrp);
        }

        return JSON.serialize(wList);
    }
    @AuraEnabled
    public static string ObjectNames()
    {

        List<SelectOption> ObjNames= new List<SelectOption>();
        ObjNames.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));
        ObjNames.add(new selectoption('Pay_Element_Master__c','Pay Element'));
        ObjNames.add(new selectoption('CTC_Master__c','CTC Master'));
        ObjNames.add(new selectoption('Section_Master__c','Section Master'));
        return JSON.serialize(ObjNames);
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static string getComponent(string wrapval,string id) {
        String objectName;
        Criteria_Master__c cmas = new Criteria_Master__c();
        List < WrapperCriteria > warpList = (List < WrapperCriteria > )System.JSON.deserialize(wrapval, List<WrapperCriteria >.class);

        system.debug('::::::wrList value::::' + warpList);
        system.debug('id value ::::::' + id);

            WrapperCriteria ac=new WrapperCriteria ();
        List < SelectOption > ObjNames = new List < SelectOption > ();
        ObjNames.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));
        ObjNames.add(new selectoption('Pay_Element_Master__c', 'Pay Element'));
        ObjNames.add(new selectoption('CTC_Master__c', 'CTC Master'));

        Map <String,String> ctcMasAPINames = new Map < String, String > ();
        cmas = [select id, Name, Action_Criteria__c, Company_Master__c from Criteria_Master__c where Id=:id];

        if (warpList.size() > 0) {
            for (WrapperCriteria wr: warpList) {
                List <SelectOption > options = new List <SelectOption > ();
                if (wr.ObjectApiNAme == 'Pay_Element_Master__c') {
                    for (SelectOption so: ObjNames) {
                        if (so.Value == wr.ObjectApiNAme) {
                            objectName = so.Label;
                            system.debug('****objectname *****' + objectName);
                        }
                    }
                    wr.SelObjectName = objectName;     //aassigned to wrapper


                    for (Pay_Element_Master__c pem: [select id, name, Company_Master__c from Pay_Element_Master__c where Company_Master__c = : cmas.Company_Master__c]) {
                        options.add(new SelectOption(pem.id, pem.name));
                        //dc.componentMap.put(pem.id,pem.name);
                        ctcMasAPINames.put(pem.id, pem.name);
                        System.debug('--------Pay element MAster MAP VAlues-----' + ctcMasAPINames);
                    }
                    ac.Components = options;

                } 
                else if (wr.ObjectApiNAme == 'CTC_Master__c') {
                    for (SelectOption so: ObjNames) {
                        if (so.Value == wr.ObjectApiNAme) {
                            objectName = so.Label;
                            system.debug('-----------objectname --------------' + objectName);
                        }
                    }
                    wr.SelObjectName = objectName;
                    Map < String, Schema.SObjectType > globalDescription = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
                    Schema.sObjectType objType = globalDescription.get('CTC_Master__c');
                    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult ob = objType.getDescribe();

                    if (ob == Null) {
                        AuraHandledException e = new AuraHandledException('Invalid sObject Type');
                        e.setMessage('Invalid sObject Type');
                        system.debug(e);
                        throw e;

                    }
                    Map < String, Schema.SObjectField > mapFieldList = ob.fields.getMap();

                    for (Schema.SObjectField field: mapFieldList.values()) {
                        Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = field.getDescribe();
                        if (fieldResult.isAccessible() && (fieldResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Integer || fieldResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Double || fieldResult.getType() == Schema.DisplayType.Currency)) {
                            options.add(new SelectOption(fieldResult.getName(), fieldResult.getLabel()));
                            //dc.componentMap1.put(fieldResult.getName(),fieldResult.getLabel());
                            ctcMasAPINames.put(fieldResult.getName(),fieldResult.getLabel());   
                        }
                    }
                    ac.Components1= options;

                }
            }
        }

        return JSON.serialize(ac);
    }


    @AuraEnabled
    public static string addRow(string wrapval,integer counterval ){
        system.debug('counter value::::'+counterval);
        List < WrapperCriteria > warpList = (List<WrapperCriteria >)JSON.deserialize(wrapval,List<WrapperCriteria >.class);

        WrapperCriteria objInnerClass = new WrapperCriteria();
        Action_Criteria__c newAc= new Action_Criteria__c();        
        objInnerClass.record = newAc;
        objInnerClass.index = counterval;
        warpList.add(objInnerClass);    
        system.debug('------warpList---->'+warpList); 
        return JSON.serialize(warpList);
    }
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void saveCall(string wrvalue,string id){
        List<Action_Criteria__c> RecordsToBeInserted=new List<Action_Criteria__c>();
        Map <String,String> ctcMasAPINames = new Map < String, String > ();
        system.debug('save functionality is calling::::');
        List < WrapperCriteria > warpList = (List < WrapperCriteria >) JSON.deserialize(wrvalue, List<WrapperCriteria >.class);
        system.debug('::::::::::::warpList::::::::::::::::'+warpList);
        system.debug('id value:::::::::::'+id);
        List<Criteria_Master__c> updatedCrimasters=new List<Criteria_Master__c>();
        Criteria_Master__c cmas = new Criteria_Master__c();

        cmas=[select id, Name, Action_Criteria__c, Company_Master__c from Criteria_Master__c where Id =:id];
        ID cid=cmas.id;
        system.debug('cid value ::::::'+cid);

        if(warpList!=null && !warpList.isEmpty())
        {
            for(WrapperCriteria wf: warpList)
            {
                system.debug('wrapper calling::::::::::::::::::::');
               // if(!string.isBlank(wf.SelObjectName) && !string.isBlank(wf.FieldName))
                //{    
                    Action_Criteria__c ac= wf.record;
                    ac.Criteria_Master__c =cid ;
                    ac.Object_Name__c=wf.SelObjectName;
                    if(wf.Operator!='None')
                    {
                        ac.Operator__c=wf.Operator;
                    }
                    ac.Object_API_Name__c=wf.ObjectApiNAme;
                    ac.Action_Criteria_API_Name__c=wf.FieldName;
                    ac.Special_operator_slash_value__c = wf.specialOperatorSlashValue;
                    ac.Special_operator_value__c = wf.specialOperatorValue;
                    // System.debug('-----fc.object api--------'+ctcMasAPINames.ContainsKey(wf.FieldName));
                    if(ctcMasAPINames.ContainsKey(wf.FieldName)) 
                    {
                        if(ac.Object_API_Name__c=='Pay_Element_Master__c')
                        {
                            ac.Action_Criteria_Field_Name__c= ctcMasAPINames.get(wf.FieldName);
                        }
                        if(ac.Object_API_Name__c=='CTC_Master__c')
                        {
                            ac.Action_Criteria_Field_Name__c= ctcMasAPINames.get(wf.FieldName);
                            System.debug('-------------'+ctcMasAPINames.get(wf.FieldName));
                        }

                    }
                    system.debug('==fc==>'+ac);
                    RecordsToBeInserted.add(ac);

                //}
            }

            system.debug('==RecordsToBeInserted==>'+RecordsToBeInserted.size());
            upsert RecordsToBeInserted;
            for(Criteria_Master__c cm:[select id,Name,Filter_Criteria__c from Criteria_Master__c where Id=:id])
            {
                string ActionCriteria;
                if(!RecordsToBeInserted.isEmpty())
                {
                    for(Action_Criteria__c ac: [select id, Object_API_Name__c,Action_Criteria_API_Name__c, Sequence_No__c, Operator__c, Criteria_Master__c from Action_Criteria__c where Criteria_Master__c=:id order by  Sequence_No__c asc])
                    {
                        if(string.isBlank(ActionCriteria))
                        {
                            ActionCriteria =  string.valueof(ac.Action_Criteria_API_Name__c);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ActionCriteria =  ActionCriteria + string.valueof(ac.Action_Criteria_API_Name__c);
                        }
                        if(ac.Operator__c=='+ Addition')
                        {
                            ActionCriteria = ActionCriteria +'+';    
                        }
                    }
                    if(!string.isBlank(ActionCriteria))
                    {
                        cm.Action_Criteria_Logic__c =  ActionCriteria;
                    }
                    cm.Action_Criteria__c =True;
                    updatedCrimasters.add(cm);
                }
            }
            update updatedCrimasters;
            system.debug('update criteria master::::::::::'+updatedCrimasters);
        }
    }
    @AuraEnabled
    public static string removeRow(string wrvalue,integer rowval){
        system.debug('::::: rowToRemove val  :::::'+rowval);

        List < WrapperCriteria > warpList = (List < WrapperCriteria > ) JSON.deserialize(wrvalue, List<WrapperCriteria >.class);
        system.debug('::::::wrList value::::' + warpList);
        rowval = Integer.valueOf(rowval);
        if(!string.isBlank(string.valueof(rowval)))
        {
            Action_Criteria__c acdelete = warpList[rowval].record;
            list<Action_Criteria__c> listAc = new list<Action_Criteria__c>();

            if(!string.isblank(acdelete.id))
            {
                Criteria_Master__c criteriaMaster = [select id,Name,Action_Criteria__c,(select id, Criteria_Master__c from Action_Criteria__r where id!=:acdelete.id ) from Criteria_Master__c where Id=:acdelete.Criteria_Master__c];
                listAc = [select id, Criteria_Master__c from Action_Criteria__c where id!=:acdelete.id and Criteria_Master__c=:acdelete.Criteria_Master__c];
                if(criteriaMaster.Action_Criteria__r.isEmpty())
                {
                    criteriaMaster.Action_Criteria__c = false;
                    update criteriaMaster;
                }
                delete acdelete;
            }
        }
        warpList.remove(rowval);
        system.debug('wraper List  *******'+warpList);
        return JSON.serialize(warpList);
    } 
}
```

Wrapper side:

```
public class WrapperCriteria
{
    @AuraEnabled
    public Criteria_Master__c  criteriaMaster {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public Integer index  {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public Action_Criteria__c record  {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public string CriteriaMasId  {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String ObjectApiNAme  {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public Criteria_Master__c CriteriaMas{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String SpecialOperator {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String SelObjectName {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String FieldName{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String Operator{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public decimal specialOperatorSlashValue{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public decimal specialOperatorValue{get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<SelectOption> ComponentsInWpr{get; set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<SelectOption> Components{get; set;}
     @AuraEnabled
    public List<SelectOption> Components1{get; set;}
    //@AuraEnabled
    //public Map<String, String> componentMap{get;set;}
    //@AuraEnabled
    //public Map<String, String> componentMap1{get;set;}



    public WrapperCriteria()
    {
        this.criteriaMaster=new Criteria_Master__c();

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the error at line - `component.set("v.option",JSON.parse(re.getReturnValue()));` ? If yes, do a `console.log` of `re.getReturnValue()` and update the question with it.

Comment: You should add few more information like what value are you passing, what are you receiving in lightning component controller. Simply posting your code and error text don't help much.

Comment: OR if you are getting the error at line `List < WrapperCriteria > warpList = (List < WrapperCriteria > ) JSON.deserialize(wrapval, List<WrapperCriteria >.class);`, let us know what value you are passing to wrapval param.

Comment: from where you setting v.wrp ?

Comment: iam not getting sucess message..It will throw error here  List < WrapperCriteria > warpList = (List < WrapperCriteria > ) JSON.deserialize(wrapval, List<WrapperCriteria >.class);

Comment: wrp is attribute in your component right ? what is the type of that attribute and where it is initialed ?

Comment: its wrapper attribute.. <aura:attribute name="wrp" type="WrapperCriteria[]"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sample codes work for me. 
Component

```
<aura:component controller="ArrayTest">
<!-- Attribute use to display objects-->
<aura:attribute name="strings" type="ArrayTest.simple[]" />

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

<p>worked</p></aura:component>
```

Here is the Controller js

```
({
init : function(component, event, helper) {
    //create simple objects
    var simples = [];
    simples.push({"a": "a","b": "b"});
    simples.push({"a": "c","b": "d"});
    //set objects into attribute
    var origns = component.set("v.strings", simples);

    var passStrs = component.get("c.getStringArrs");
    passStrs.setParams({ "strs" : JSON.stringify(component.get("v.strings")) });//pass parameter

    passStrs.setCallback(this, function(response){
        let state = response.getState();

        if( state === 'SUCCESS') {
            console.log('good');
        } 

    });
    $A.enqueueAction(passStrs);
}})
```

Here is the server side class

```
public class ArrayTest {

@AuraEnabled
public static void getStringArrs(string strs) {
    System.debug(strs);
    List<simple> fieldList = (List<simple>) JSON.deserialize(strs, List<simple>.class);
    system.debug(fieldList[0]);
}

public class simple {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String a {get; set;}

    @AuraEnabled
    public String b {get; set;}

}}
```

Basically you should pass objects as a string into server side, and you could deserialize the string to be list of objects you want. However, if the parameter string is not a good JSON file. You will get that error. For example, when the strs in my sample code is like '({'a':'b', 'b':'c'})', I will get the same error as yours.

Please hope this will inspire you to get rid of your error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are adding code to do the deserialization? That is usually best left to the framework to reduce the amount of code you need to write and avoid problems like unexpected encoding.

So the Apex would look like this:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static WrapperCriteria getComponent(WrapperCriteria[] warpList, Id id) {
    system.debug('::warpList:: ' + warpList);
    system.debug('::id::' + id);
    ...
    return ac;
}
```

assuming this in the component:

```
<aura:attribute name="wrp" type="WrapperCriteria[]"/>
```

Comment: Then I got this error:  System.QueryException: Dynamic query yields incompatible SObject type String for loop variable of type WrapperCriteria   @Keith C

Comment: @AnnappaPH I don't see a dynamic `Database.query` call in your Apex so can't offer help on that.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all `JSON.parse();` calls Aura automatically does the same, also don't use `JSON.serialize();` and change the return type to the type you are passing to `JSON.serialize();`

Just return the type and use in `Action.setCallback`;